# Remove border line via css in R distill blog

Tags: html, css, r

My css understanding is unfortunately rather limited and I am struggeling with the following:

I am using R's distill package which allows to produce blogs based on the distill framework. The appearance of these blogs can be somewhat modified by the use of css.

I am trying to remove a horizontal line (= border). I identified the pertaining css entry when inspecting the source of the blog page, i.e. unchecking the pertaining field has the desired result. However, copying

```
d-byline {
    border-top:0px !important
    }
```

into the blog's css file and recompiling the blog has no effect.

I am wondering whether there is something to this border which makes it impossible to modify via css?

A post showcasing the issue is [here](https://test-clean.netlify.app/post/2021-01-01-test-css/).
The css file can be seen [here](https://github.com/werkstattcodes/distill_clean/blob/master/theme.css):

Many thanks for any hint.

Comment: If `d-byline` is a class name, it should be `.d-byline`

Comment: @HaoWu many thanks. That did the trick. Happy to accept your reply as an answer.